# How to Drag the game object in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay, so I am preparing a game of Ludo with only two players having 4 pawns each. I am using a dice which is when clicked will rotate randomly giving an output.

While dragging the pawn the y axis is also decreasing. So when the blue pawn is dragged towards red one it will go under the board(which should not happen.) How to figure it out?

Here's my C# code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

RequireComponent(typeof(MeshCollider))]
public class DragPawn : MonoBehaviour
{

private Vector3 screenPoint;
private Vector3 offset;

void OnMouseDown()
{
    screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
    offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));

}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
    Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset; 
    transform.position = curPosition;
}

}
```

**Here's the image with the problem**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your board is using a vertical axis of Z and an horizontal axis of X. But i think your code is using X and Y.

Regardless, i think your offset variable should use '0' in the axis in which it should be locked, since you are adding it to the transform, if it is non-zero you will be modifying that axis.

**Edit:**

Just think about it, you want to add to only 2 dimensions of a 3 dimensional structure. If your object is at, say, [15, 10, 8] and you want to move it up 10 in the X direction you have to add to the X dimension only. (`[10, 0, 0]`)

`[15, 10, 8] + [10, 0, 0] = [25, 10, 8]`

I suspect your offset variable looks something like `[10, 0, 2]` or something, so when you add it, you're adding to the Z dimension when you don't intend to.

ie: `[15, 10, 8] + [10, 0, 2] = [25, 10, 10]`

Comment: Can you please mention in the code form I tried doing offset value 0 and also tried to put screenpoint.y instead of InputMousePosition.Y but still it is has no proper movement.